# How to parse fraction to a number?

Tags: string-manipulation, number-representation

Considering a fraction:

```
val = "F \!\(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(1\)]\)";
```

I extract the part of interest:

```
>>    res = StringTake[val, {5, StringLength@val - 1}]
<<    "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(1\)]\)"
```

Now  want to check if `res` is greater that 0 or no. How can I parse `res` to a number?

Thanks!

Comment: `Times @@ ToExpression@StringCases[res, NumberString] > 0`, but I have to wonder why you're doing such machinations with this and your prior question re: numbers in strings...

Comment: @ciao, I have two parts: representation and validation.

Comment: I think Divide @@ ToExpression@StringCases[res, NumberString] > 0 instead of Times ....

Comment: I think since only sign matters `Times` also works?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard what can we do about that topic? :)

Comment: @Kuba Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Is this easy to find in documentation or worth an answer?

Comment: It is easy indeed.